# NVARCHAR and VARCHAR conversion cause index scan

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

```
declare @p0 nvarchar(4000)
select id_t_s from table1 where id_t = @p0
```

This will be index scan, because id_t column is varchar(100).  it will takes145 ms. There is a warning from execution plan.

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(100),tables1.[id_t],0)=[@P0]) may affect "SeekPlan" in query plan choice.

If I change it to below:

```
declare @p0 nvarchar(4000)
select id_t_s from table1 where id_t = @p0
```

This will be index scan, because id_t column is varchar(100). took 0 ms.

```
declare @p0 varchar(4000)
select id_t_s from table1 where id_t = @p0
```

This will be index seek. It will takes 0 ms.

Is there any way to fix it without change code or table?

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: If your column data type is `varchar` then the data type of your variable must match, otherwise as you have already noted you'll have an inplicit conversion which is not sargable. What exactly needs fixing?

Answer (score 3):

Try this WHERE clause.

```
WHERE id_t = CAST(@p0 AS VARCHAR(4000))
```

This will allow the server to compare the values in the column to data of the same type. That lets it do the index seek you want.

Consider defining your @p0 variable so it has the same data type as your table's column. As you have it, you're trying to look up a Unicode value in a 8-bit (ASCII, latin1) column. SQL server does it for you, but slower than you might like.

Comment: Yeah, also convert function working well. My goal is don’t have to change code or table definition.

Comment: The mismatch of query items with the data types in table fields will cause seeking all rows of the database  and it will ignore the indices in the database. In tables with large number of rows it will cause drastic degradation of query performance and it will impose large CPU and I/O overheads on SQL Server.